# Reputation number not visible on main page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, reputation, top-bar

This is a very minor bug, but the reputation number seems not to be visible on the main site:

[image]

Interestingly, it *is* visible in meta:

[image]

Comment: Huh, I can see mine on the home page, but I have reputation visible for all users. (Double checking: when I hide all user rep, then it goes away.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**2 August, 2022 update: We have implemented a fix, finally. Hopefully this will survive any UI redesign in the near future.**

---

Yes. I noticed that as soon as the front page changes were happening, but from what I gather, a lot of people are unhappy about the new design, so before we go ahead and start messing with the script again, I want to wait and see if there's any imminent changes coming up.

It is unfortunate, but since it's not in my direct control to "just update the script" we sometimes need to live with these things. One can argue, however, that it is in the spirit of the reputation hiding feature, and that there is nothing to fix. Still, we'll give the interface a bit more time before we try and deal with that.

Comment: +1 for: "it is in the spirit of the reputation hiding feature, and that there is nothing to fix." So from this viewpoint, it is a feature, not a bug. :-)

Comment: The behaviour that the reputation first visibly appears for a split second and then disappears, widening the search box in the process, is *definitely* a bug, and it’s quite annoying.

Comment: It is nicer on mobile, I'll give this bug that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila not sure if this is the same exact UI issue, but it seems to be back as of 2023-11-07-UTC or earlier

Comment: @micsthepick What do you mean?

Comment: hmm, it might be browser/extension specific, or fixed already? I'll pull out my work PC again - EDIT: it's still there on my work PC, even on latest chrome in icognito mode

Comment: it's happening wherever there is mathjax getting parsed if I were to guess, or during the operation that it is part of

Comment: oh I see, this is happening wherever there are reputation boxes on the main page and Q and A pages